# thymeleaf and spring boot form exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to add data to my database and reload the same page using spring boot and thymeleaf but when I save data I face this error

org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.closure.gcp.entities.QuestionEntity'; nested exception
is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value 'adsf'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "adsf"

controller code :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/Questions")
public class QuestionView {
    @Autowired
    QuestionRepo questionRepo;

    @RequestMapping(path = "/")
    public String index(@ModelAttribute("question") QuestionEntity question, Model model)
    {
        List<QuestionEntity> list = questionRepo.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("questions", list);
        return "Questions";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addQuestion(Model model,@ModelAttribute("question") QuestionEntity question) {
        
        questionRepo.save((QuestionEntity)model.getAttribute("question"));

        List<QuestionEntity> list = questionRepo.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("questions", list);
        return "Questions";
    }
    

}
```

thymeleaf page :

```
 <html>
    <header>
        <title>Questions</title>
    </header>
    <body>
        <h2>hello questions</h2>
        <hr>
        <tr th:each="q: ${questions}">
            <td th:text="${q.question}"></td>
            <br>
            <td th:text="${q.question_type}"></td>
            <hr>
          </tr>
          <!-- <form  th:action="@{/add}" th:object="${question}" method="post"> -->
          <form  action="./add" th:object="${question}" method="POST">
            <input type="text" th:field="*{question}" />
            <br >
            <input type="text" th:field="*{question_type}" />
            <br >
            <input type="submit" value="save" >
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="question")
public class QuestionEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Integer id;


    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String question;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String question_type;

    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
private InterestEntity interest;


    @ManyToOne(optional = true)
    private LevelEntity level;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String sup_file;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int pionts;


    @ManyToMany
    private List<ContestEntity> contest;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy ="question")
    private List<AnswerEntity> answers;
// getters and setters
}
```

**notice** *when I try to open another page in "/add" it works*

Comment: The exception clearly says that there's a mismatch of form data and `QuestionEntity`. It expects integer for a field and it's getting a string. Check your form and entity again.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the code of `QuestionEntity`?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe Iadded QuestionEntity

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan the field is String in the entity so I'm asking why it is not working

Answer (score 1):

It is better to have 2 separate methods, one for GET and one for POST and to use redirect after the POST (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). This is how I would code this based on your separate `QuestionModel` class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/Questions")
public class QuestionView {
    @Autowired
    QuestionRepo questionRepo;

    @GetMapping
    public String index(Model model)
    {
        List<QuestionEntity> list = questionRepo.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("questions", list);
        model.addAttribute("question", new QuestionModel());
        return "Questions";
    }

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String addQuestion(@Valid @ModelAttribute("question") QuestionModel question, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
        
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
          return "Questions";
        }

        questionRepo.save(new QuestionEntity().question(question.getQuestion()).question_type(question.getQuestion_type()));

        return "redirect:/Questions";
    }   
}
```

Main points:

1. Use separate methods for GET and POST
2. Add the `@Valid` annotation to the `@ModelAttribute` in the POST method so any validation annotations on `QuestionModel` are checked (Because you probably want to make sure the question has at least some text in it for example).
3. Use `BindingResult` as parameter to check if there are validation errors.
4. Use `"redirect:"` to force a new GET after the POST to help avoid double submissions if a user would refresh the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to solve

I just made a model class and use it instead of entity

and I used just one method to handle index and add requests

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/Questions")
public class QuestionView {
    @Autowired
    QuestionRepo questionRepo;

    @RequestMapping(path = {"/",""},method = {RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
    public String index(@ModelAttribute("question") QuestionModel question, Model model,HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        if(request.getMethod().equals("POST"))
        {
            questionRepo.save(new QuestionEntity().question(question.getQuestion()).question_type(question.getQuestion_type()));
        }
        List<QuestionEntity> list = questionRepo.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("questions", list);
        return "Questions";
    }
}
```

Comment: Not such a good way to do this. You might want to read up on form handling here: https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/05/23/form-handling-with-thymeleaf/